# Show that every point of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

How can one show that every point of the set of natural numbers, $\mathbb{Q}$,   is a limit point of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: That means there is a point of Q in every neighbourhood of a point of Q.

Comment: Every metric space is a neighborhood of all of its points. Does this answer your question?

Comment: If $x \in X$ is a point in a topological space, then $N$ is a neighborhood of $x$ if there is an open set $U \subseteq N$ so that $x \in U$. Since $X$ is open, $X$ is always a neighborhood for all its points.

Comment: @Patrick  Do not put words in a users mouth.

Answer (score 1):

The fancy term for "every point of $\mathbb Q$ is a limit point" is that $\mathbb Q$ is [dense in itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense-in-itself).

A topological space is always a "neighborhood of all of its points", so that is not a useful way of saying it.

On the other hand, $\mathbb Q$ is not a neighborhood *in $\mathbb R$* of anything. Being a neighborhood is always something that is relative to a particular topological space.

If you have a *subset* of a topological space that happens to be a neighborhood of each of its points, that means neither more nor less than the set is *open*. ($\mathbb Q$ is definitely not open in $\mathbb R$).